How would you say "get twisted up", as in "The future that we dreamed of got all twisted up somehow." in Latin?
I'm trying to translate the lyrics of the Eric Bogle's song The Gift of Years into Latin. One stanza goes like this:

The country that you died for, mate,you wouldn't know it now.The future that we dreamed of, mate,got all twisted up somehow.

My attempt would be:

Terra ad quem mortuus es tunc,eam non scires nunc.Ventura quem in somnio videbamus, ea omnis cambiavit quodam modo.

But I am quite sure there is a better word than "cambiavit". So, which one is it?

I believe torqueo would be appropriate because, when referring to general conditions, the participle can mean confused, complicated or awry.
I would translate it as follows:

Terram cui mortuus es, amice,
iam non cognosceres.
Futura quae somniis videbamus, amice,
aliqua omnino torquentur.

Notes:

Terram should be in the accusative as the object of cognosceres.
The dative is appropriate, so I used cui.
Cognosco expresses recognition, whereas scio doesn't.
Futura is plural, so quae and torquentur have to be in the plural as well.

